# develop a phonegapp application

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to develop a phone gapp app but I find the documentation a little confusing.

As far as I understand, I can just write my app, choosing any directory layout I want except that index.html and config.xml need be on the first hierarchy level and then zip it and upload it to PhoneGapBuilder.

It says on the website of PhoneGapBuilder that I should leave the reference to the PhoneGap.js but remove the PhoneGap.js files from my project.

My question is: Where do I get that PhoneGap.js file? Do I download it from the apache cordova github repo?

Most tutorials show how to make an app using XCode or Eclipse, however, I want to use PhoneGapBuilder to be independent of any IDE and platform.

Where exactly do I get the necessary files to just start developing a phonegap app on my computer, with my editor of choice, using xampp and the ripple emulator?

Comment: When I was working with PhoneGap I have never used any IDEs, only a text editor as Notepad++ and the terminal (was working with ubuntu at the time). You can build the app with first specifying the platform and then just release. If this doesn't make sense to you I can seek for some good tutorials I stored somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you give a try to [build.phonegap](http://build.phonegap.com) ?
This "build" platform is far easier for newbies than installing Phonegap and so on.

Once, you read 1 or 2 pages [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics) or even if you do not read and just modify the mock up config file you will be able to convert HTML5, CSS projects to mobile apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: The thing I dont get is: There is a cordova.js file referenced in the index.html of the sampe phongap app. Where is that file? How can I develop the app on my desktop if I dont have that file?

Comment: You do not have to use cordova.js etc. if you are going to develop your application via the build phonegap platform. Check the [example config](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics) for the requirements.

Comment: Alright, I got it now, now I have a different problem :) Thanks! (The new problem, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197979/phonegapp-localfilesystem-is-not-defined)