# phonegapp - LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova

I downloaded the sample app from the phonegap builder page and edited the index.js file like this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert("DEVICE-READY!")
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, this.onFSSuccess, this.onError);
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    }
```

The deviceready event is fired but I still get the error that LocalFileSystem is not defined. I am running this in chrome using the ripple emulator.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK you can't access the filesystem by using ripple, try it on a real device or use genymotion to emulate android devices: https://www.genymotion.com